# Github Sync Fails

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I'm new to github. I've the following situation which depicts my problem.

Suppose there are X and Y developing something with a public repository in github.
X has made a few changes in his local files and Y also has made changes to his local copy.

Suppose my Y commits, X cannot sync just because he has come local changes. Github says to commit X changes first and then sync.
When X tries to commit, Github gives a HEAD not found error or something.

My question is how can both X and Y develop something together with commits and sync happening  randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an excellent free book called [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book) that does a good job of explaining how Git works and how to use it.